# How to define generic typescript type with keyof property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to have a generic type to use it in some function as an argument, but it is not clear how to define a property that would have strongly typed property names (**specificProperties** in example code snippet).

```
type Config<T> = {
    specificProperties: keyof T[],
    data: T[],
}

function doSomething<T>(config: Config<T>) {
    // Some logic here
}
```

Usage:

```
type Test = {
    code: string,
    name: string,
}

const config: Config<Test> = {
    specificProperties: [ 'code' ], //Typescript error here
    data: [
        {
            code: 'a',
            name: 'b'
        }
    ]
}

doSomething(config)
```

Typescript throws an error: **Types of property 'specificProperties' are incompatible. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'keyof T[]'.**

It seems Config type should be fixed, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Uh, this is just an operator precedence confusion; it's `(keyof T)[]`; if you write `keyof T[]` the compiler interprets it as `keyof (T[])`.

Comment: @jcalz Could you propose a solution how to fix the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `keyof T[]` to `(keyof T)[]`. The brackets have a higher priority than the `keyof` operator.

```
type Config<T> = {
    specificProperties: (keyof T)[],
    data: T[],
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8AoKcqAZ0gGMVUaAFAJzkmeBQkoC4oAKANYQQcJFCwBKANoBdADRkKAEwCGwVXyxzFAXxIkkAVwQ1OiKMrgBlOAFsIwABYoEmXPxqJUaPvGTo2DiSxErkAPThULYOUAA2cGgoNFBOEMwQJPokoJAS3MAEoRRQXsoQfJTAzK5oiiUIqg6V1bV6Bl4IVaXe6H697gV4hKQl1BB0DCxs6ZzcfNJQAORlEEtQClCRWODcNDVghemszKnpmSVqGgthJcV3D6t8S6pL9Q93jc3LAEZLtyV9CVZFkDFYYo4XG5PANJEA)

Comment: you got in there first! here's a TypeScript Playground showing this working: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtQMYHsATCALikQCcBLAOwHMAaLHGgQwFtTzhr6mBfDBgI1EefDQBmVOmQDCE6XQA8cRAD4U6ZtniRcVabgAKFfJArAqCMgG0oAcgLEHUALoMoAei8xwCXGowJAgKMwooAAtQiB0oQlZgVjs4nG00jJxnLgdWByZMzLZOMgcAIwdUnEE0twxBDFBIKAUpGVVNVEw0vQgDI1NzUKsbKAAKAGsIEHxJWABKWw84hKSyGCWBDCA

Comment: specificProperties was being set to `keyof an array (of T)` rather than `an array of keyof T` which is what you wanted